# Why Is c++'s "this" designed to be a pointer instead of the pointed object?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, this

I came across the following function  definition from a c++ textbook:

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a) {

  double* p = new double[a.sz]; 
  for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i) 
        p[i] = a.elem[i]; 
  delete[] elem; 
  elem=p;
  sz=a.sz;
  return *this;
}
```

I have a question about the last statement -- which returns `*this` instead of `this`. As far as I remember, `this` in Java  refers to the current object. Am I correct that `this` in C++ refers to the pointer to the current object? If so, why  is it designed in that way? Thanks.

Comment: Note that Java doesn't have the notion of pointers or non-primitive values

Comment: @Caleth • What Java terminology calls a _reference_, C++ terminology calls a _pointer_.

Comment: @Eljay No, C++ has both references and pointers, which are *both* distinct from Java references. E.g. you can rebind a Java reference, you can do arithmetic to; and take the address of; a C++ pointer.

Comment: @Caleth • Actually, yes, Java references are C or C++ pointers.  The NullPointerException is remnant terminology from before marketing made the decision to alter the terminology (because "pointers are evil").  In C and C++, a pointer can be rebound to a new address.  Java does not provide the means to take an address of or perform arithmetics on a Java reference, but that is merely reducing what is allowed on a Java reference (C or C++ pointer).  The difference in Java (references) versus C or C++ (pointers) is merely one of each language's particular terminology.

Comment: @Eljay A reference is indistinguishable from the object to which it refers. A pointer is a separate object. My point is that C++ has two distinct things, both of which have similarities with aspects of Java's references

Comment: @Caleth • My point is that in Java the term "reference" is the same thing in C or C++ as the the term "pointer".